# In 3 three power system, can damage occurs from incorrectly connected phases?

Tags: power

A three phase generator, no grid involved, phase 1 connected to phase 3 on the load, and phase connected to phase 1 on load, what is going to happen?

Comment: First you have the whole Y vs Delta question, and then you have the motors thing, then the swapped phases. Please clarify.

Comment: Just swapped phase on the load, I removed my assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What will happen, is that any three-phase AC motors powered locally
will reverse their rotation direction.   That might break some items, will
definitely inconvenience folk with right-handed twist drills, when
their drill press, under power, can only back out of the hole.  Table
saws will aim their gums at the cut instead of their teeth.  Big fans
will stop exhausting and start intaking.

Don't use the elevator.

Reversing a squirrel-cage blower  motor might make bad noises and lose efficiency, but will still blow forward.   Sump pumps, too, will still pump the right direction.

A few 'starter' circuits consist of auxiliary motors of varieties
other than 3phase AC, and the large motors that use those starters will
spin up as usual, then try to change direction.  Expect to replace fuses.

Comment: What about loads other than motor?

Comment: Motors and transformers use 3-phase power.   Lighting doesn't (there's only two terminals on an incandescent filament), nor do any DC power systems in common use; some very old motor-generator sets  for welding would change polarity (if you have 1940s-era welding gear).